# Ruby on Rails: Call controller method on specific model from view

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, view, model, controller

I am new to Ruby and Rails. 
I have a view that displays a list of course offerings.

```
<% if defined?@offerings %>
   .....
<% @offerings.each do |offering| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%=offering.semester %></td>
      <td><%=offering.location %></td>
    </tr>
  <%end %>
```

I need to add an enroll button that is associated with each offering. This enroll button should call an offerings controller method that decrements the specific offerings capacity attribute.

How can I bind each button to its respective offering? Or alternatively how can I pass the correct offering as a parameter to the controller method?

Answer (score 0):

Add another `<td>`, like this :

```
<td><%= link_to "Enroll", your_method_path(offering) %></td>
```

Comment: I saw this online but I am very confused about what goes in to your_method_path(offering)?

Comment: You have to add the route to your method in config/routes.rb if it's not done yet. Then, to find the path you can use this in your terminale : rake routes and it will tell you the path for your method.

Comment: can you please be more specific, I am very new to rails. Running rake routes I get :  PUT    /offerings/:id(.:format)      offerings#update.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [button_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to) method, which will submit a POST request by default, like this:

`<td><%= button_to "Enroll", enroll_offering_path(offering) %></td>`

For `enroll_offering_path` to work you need:

- A `PUT /offerings/:id/enroll` route:

  ```
  # config/routes.rb`

  resources :offerings do
    post 'enroll', on: :member
  end
  ```
- and `#enroll` controller action:

  ```
  # app/controllers/offerings_controller.rb

  class OfferingsController < ApplicationController
    ...
    def enroll
      # Here you would do something like...
      @offering = Offering.find(params[:id])
      @offering.decrement!(:capacity)
    end
  end
  ```

You can read more about how all of this works [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).